# Error java.sql.SQLException: No database selected al solicitar que muestre los datos de la tabla

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

Hola chic@s he escrito el código que se muestra pero no entiendo porque me sale el error java.sql.SQLException: No database selected. He comprobado la librería mysql.jar y esta bien. Tambien he comprobado que los datos de acceso esten correctos y asi es, porque el programa me muestra por consola el mensaje de conexión realizada. ¿Podeis ayudarme a encontrar el fallo? Muchas gracias comunidad.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Conexion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String parametros = "jdbc:mysql://remotemysql.com:3306";
        final String usuario = "user";
        final String pass = "1234";

        try {

            Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(parametros, usuario, pass);

            System.out.println("Conexión realizada!!");

            Statement s = c.createStatement();
            
            ResultSet r = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM EfrenConcesionario");
            
            while(r.next()) {
                
                System.out.println(r.getString("PK_ConcesionarioID") + " " + r.getString("NombreConcesionario"));;
            }
            
            c.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Veamos... el error te está indicando que no tienes una base de datos seleccionada, y en tu string de conexión... no hay ninguna base de datos!! Según la documentación el string de conexión es `jdbc:mysql://HOST/DATABASE`, tienes la primera parte pero te falta indicar la base de datos en el string `parametros`, quedería algo así: `final String parametros = "jdbc:mysql://remotemysql.com:3306/NombreDeTuDB";`

Comment: Oh dios, como he podido tener un fallo tan tonto. No era capaz de verlo. Me concentre en que el fallo pudiera ser mas dificil. Muchas gracias Benito B.

Comment: Créeme, eso es muy común. Siempre es más fácil encontrar el error en código ajeno que en código propio, porque en nuestra cabeza lo que hicimos está correcto y lo *ignoramos* al revisar :)